# Sticky footer container that doesn't overlap other content

Tags: html, css

I have a `sidenav` which has a container with social media context that is meant to stick to the bottom of the `sidenav` which spans the entire view-port height like so:

```
sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  background: #007979;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align:
  width: 25rem;
}
```

The `sidenav` immediate child is a container which has it's `position` property set to relative to I can then assign a `position` property and value to the social media container to stick to the bottom, like so:

```
sidenav-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

My issue is that if I set the social media containers `position` property to either `absolute` or `relative`, if the view-port height is adjusted slightly, the social media container overlaps the navigation list that is at the top, as it is positioned in correspondence to the `sidenav-inner` container.

***Question***

How do I position the social media container at the bottom of the `sidenav`, without using the `position` proeprty? Or how do I use the `position` property without it overlapping other content in the `sidenav`?

```
<nav class="sidenav"> 
    <div class="sidenav-inner"> 
        <div class="sidenav-header"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <img src="/"> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav"> 
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="side-nav-social"> 
            <div> 
                //social media content
            </div> 
            //more social media content
        </div>
    </div> 
 </nav>
```

Comment: _“How do I position the social media container at the bottom of the sidenav, without using the position proeprty?”_ - flexbox.

Comment: Meaning, can I use another container set to a specific height? Or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily solve this by defining .sidenav-inner as a flexbox and then having the header and footer not grow, but the ul grow to take up all the space. It will thus push the social media to the bottom of the box.

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  background: #007979;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align:
  width: 25rem;
}

.sidenav-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidenav-header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.sidenav-inner ul {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.side-nav-social {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2u85u4q/

Comment: Of course. Having one of those mornings. Thank you @Sorcy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:(be aware of margins)
**html**

```
        <nav class="sidenav"> 
    <div class="sidenav-inner"> 
        <div class="sidenav-header"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                header
                    <img src="/"> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav sidenav-body"> 
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
                        <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
                        <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="side-nav-social"> 
            <div> 
                //social media content
            </div> 
            //more social media content
        </div>
    </div> 
 </nav>
```

**css:**

```
    .sidenav {
  height: 250px;
  background: #007979;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidenav-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 90%;
}
.sidenav-header{
  height:10%;
}
.sidenav-body{
  overflow:auto;
  height:70%;
}
.side-nav-social{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:10%;
}
```

[plnker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/eDCSCNWe8T52LIoyRpXD)